# regular expression to extract fraction, decimal and number from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

I need a regex to extract fraction, decimal and integer values from a given string. For example, an input will be like following.

- 1/2 apples
- 1.5 orange
- 2.5 orange
- 1 lemon

And output should be following.

- 1/2
- 1.5
- 2.5
- 1

I figured out how to extract fraction, decimal and integer values separately using 3 different regex, but I can't figure out a way to extract all the possible number values with one regex.

I'm currently using Javascript String object's match method.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Awesome, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Use regex pattern

```
\d+([/.]\d+)?
```

...which leads to Javascript code

```
var n = str.match(/\d+([\/.]\d+)?/g);
```

Check [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/zsa6jtmv/) fiddle/demo.

Comment: @ohaal - Check the fiddle/demo.

Answer (score 1):

Then why not present your working regexes?

But here is how, simply use an alternation:

```
\d+(\/\d+|\.\d+)?
```

This is already slightly optimized. You could simply separate your three regexes by `|`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest possible regular expression in this case (assuming that your numbers always in the beginning of the string) is:

```
^\S+
```

Examples:

```
'1/2 apples'.match(/^\S+/) // ["1/2"]
'1 lemon'.match(/^\S+/) // ["1"]
```

Comment: i may have simplified the problems too much. The string also contains the '/' character.

Comment: @user1721547: your last comment doesn't make much sense. Where it contains it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all strings have the same format (i.e. starts with amount, then space, then text), there is even no need in regular expression:

```
"1/2 apples".split(" ").shift();   // gives "1/2"
```